# shape match parent

Tags: android, progress-bar, drawable, shapes

I write a custom ProgressBar like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- Custom progressbar with background -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Background -->
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/colorOrange" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <!-- Progressbar -->
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <!-- toDegrees set very high to increase rotation speed  -->
        <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:toDegrees="1800">
            <shape
                android:innerRadius="25dp"
                android:shape="ring"
                android:thickness="4dp"
                android:useLevel="false">
                <!-- Set colors -->
                <gradient
                    android:endColor="@color/colorBlue"
                    android:startColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:type="sweep" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

My goal is to build a ProgressBar to hide the entire layout with a background while data is loading.

Anyway when I insesert progressbar in layout with tags:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

I the backgroud of progressbar do not fill entire layout, but only a square at the center of the screen:
[image: custom pb]

Why this? How can I obtain my goal ?

Comment: Why not use a progressBar in relative layout of `match_parent` height and width instead ?

Comment: check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39542227/8399299)

Comment: Yes, I know this is a smart and fast solution. But I found more stimulant to build a single component that takes care of everything.

Answer (score 0):

Try the layout below, it should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/pb"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/cu"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/cu"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:indeterminate="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Note: cu is your custom drawable in your question.

Comment: Yes, using the progressbar like your post inside my coordinatorlayout the drawable occupy all the layout ( match parent ).
Anyway the circle is stationary and not runs. I built my drawable to be a round indeterminate progressbar.I do not think the "attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal" is the correct style. But if I set "attr/progressBarStyle" my drawable seems to not be considered and appears the standard progressbar.

Comment: Try the layout above. The key here is to set the indeterminateDrawable property.